# The x-values in a line chart of JavaFX are not ordered properly / messed up?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, linechart

I am working on some Graphs using JavaFX, and I use a few line charts to get my result. There is however a problem. I think that the following code will explain what I'm trying to do:

```
while(startTime.getTimeInMillis() <= endTime.getTimeInMillis()) {
    int index = getIndex(startTime);
    if(index != -1) {
        N k = dataList.get(index);
        Data<String, N> point = new Data<String, N>(distanceList.get(index) + "", k);
        series.getData().add(point);
    }
    int newMinutes = startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+5;
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, newMinutes);
}
```

This code fills a series (JavaFX [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html)) and other code sets it in a chart which is not the problem. The above code retrieves the index by using the time. The indexes retrieved are all in ascending order, I already checked that. The distanceList is a list in ascending order and the dataList is not.

So all the datapoints in the series are added with the x values in an ascending order, but whenever this is set, I get a graph where all the X labels are messed up (and therefore also the line itself). The x labels don't have equal spacing and sometimes are over each other. I searched the internet and found some similar problems of others, which some of them said it was a bug in JavaFX. I am running the newest version of Java and JavaFX, respectively 1.8 and 8.

Everything is working fine, all values are correct as I checked it multiple times. It's just the labels on x-axis that are not shown properly. I have no clue in what the problem is, do some of you know?

Comment: Unless you really intended to loop through a single hour over and over, you should probably change `startTime.set` to `startTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5)`.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) depicting your issue

Comment: No, I didn't. I came to the conclusion that it had to be a bug in JavaFX at the time. I didn't check whether the bug is resolved or not.